# Trying to Connect Python With a PostgreSQL DB with SSH Tunnel

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh

I'm trying to connect my script to a PostgreSQL database via sshtunnel and psycopg2. I can access the DB with my credentials through DBeaver. So, basically I have this:

[SSH Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Hka.png)

Where the SSH paramateres are similar to this:

Host/IP: 'someproxy.something.io'
User Name: 'User1'
Private key: Path to an id_rsa file
Passphrase: 'Password1'

This is my code:

```
try:

    print('Connecting to the postgre database...')

   

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(

            "someproxy.something.io",

            ssh_username = "User1",

            ssh_private_key = "C:/~ /.ssh/User1_id_rsa",

            ssh_private_key_password = "Password1",

            remote_bind_adress = ("mydatabase-postgres.something.io", 5432)

    ) as server:

        server.start()
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown arguments: {'remote_bind_adress': ('mydatabase-postgres.something.io', 5432)}
```

Comment: Spelling counts `remote_bind_adress` should be `remote_bind_address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the parameter name: `remote_bind_adress -> remote_bind_address`.